# Pinescript- How to get the highest/lowest volume by price in a candle?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm wondering of how I could get the highest/lowest volume by price in a candle. Let's say I'm using a 30 minutes TF, every candle do have it's own volume; but idk how the volume spread out in the candle. I need some insights of how I could achieve this, as it is quite challenging for me.

I got some thoughts of how to do it though, maybe divide the price to sections and put the volume of where the section hits? Just like classifications? It's not that clear haha. Sorry if my guess is wrong though. Any insights would be helpful! :)

My goal is to use the highest/lowest volume by price of every candle as the source for my Anchored VWAP, so here is my Anchored VWAP code:

```
// This Pine Script™ code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © Tenozen

//@version=5
indicator("Anchored VWAP", overlay=true)

src = input.source(hlc3, "Source")
p_bool = input.bool(false, "Use Fixed Price?")
startCalculationDate = input.time(timestamp("03 Mar 2024"), "Start Calculation", confirm=true)
mult = input.float(2, "Deviation Multiplier", minval=1)

//Anchored VWAP

var pvol = array.new_float()
var vol = array.new_float()
var ppvol = array.new_float()

if startCalculationDate <= time
    array.push(pvol, src*volume)
    array.push(vol, volume)
    array.push(ppvol, src*src*volume)
else
    array.clear(pvol), array.clear(vol)

sum_pvol = array.sum(pvol)
sum_vol = array.sum(vol)
sum_ppvol = array.sum(ppvol)
vwap = sum_pvol/sum_vol
    
dev = math.sqrt(sum_ppvol/sum_vol - vwap*vwap)*mult

plot(vwap, "VWAP", linewidth=2)
plot(vwap+dev, "Upper", linewidth=2)
plot(vwap-dev, "Lower", linewidth=2)
```